# Chain State monads with Scala Cats

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I'm trying to chain a few sequential operations in a functional way with Scala and Cats. They look perfect separately but I'm not sure how can I chain them now with a flatMap / for comprehension.

So, let's say, I have something like

```
import cats.data.State

object Step1 {
    def apply() = State[String, Seq[String]] { text =>
        val ans = text.trim.split("""[\s]+""").toSeq
        (text, ans)
    }
}

println(Step1().run("Lorem Ipsum Dolor").value)

object Step2 {
    def apply() = State[Seq[String], Seq[String]] { terms =>
        val ans = terms.map(_.toLowerCase)
        (terms, ans)
    }
}

println(Step2().run(Seq("Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor")).value)
```

Ideally, I'd like to have something like

```
for {
    a <- Step1()
    b <- Step2()
} yield (b)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need state monads if you return the same state as was given? These look like simple functions to me.

Comment: In addition to what Cyrille said, your two computations have a different type of state, so they aren't compatible per se. Your example looks much more like you have functions `f1: String => Seq[String` and `f2: Seq[String] => Seq[String]` and are looking for composition `f1 andThen f2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note of your types:

For your `Step1`, you have `State[String, Seq[String]]`.
For your `Step2`, you have `State[Seq[String], Seq[String]]`.

The function `flatMap` takes in an argument of `M[A]` and `A => M[B]` and returns `M[B]` but clearly your `M[_]` for `Step1` and `Step2` are clearly different even though they are both using the `State` datatype.

Take note that `State` has a type signature of `* -> * -> *` or it looks something like `State[S, A]` where your `S` is your "state" and `A` is your value.

In this case, if you really want to `flatMap` the two distinct `State` then you have to first "adjust" and equate the `S` of one of them.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating!